# Symfony4 Override FosUserBundle Template

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony4

I'm following this : https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_templates.html

I found the default template inside `vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bunfle/views/layout.html.twig`

The documentation is then saying to place your new layout template at `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig`. Thing is, in Symfony4 there is nore more app folder I think. How should I do that then ? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are right, and this is because the documentation is not updated for Symfony 4. What you need to do is copy all the templates files from `vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/views` and put them in a directory you create in `/templates/bundles/FOSUserBundle`. You can then edit the files in your newly created directory which will override the default templates.

Answer (score 6):

In Symfony4, you can override it by placing your template in `src/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views` instead of `templates/bundles/FOSUserBundle` (yes, sadly not in `templates` directory)

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 4.4 the right place to override the FOSUserBundle templates is :

```
app/Ressources/FOSUserBundle/views
```

[image]

This work perfect in my project